# How to get custom field from BuddyPress Extended Profile

Tags: buddypress

I'm working on some new project using BuddyPress, and one of the core features requires some information from a custom profile field. This field is a dropdown, so I only have 4 possible results. So well, it looked really simple to get this field, but I can't get it to work. I'm using the following code to get this field:

```
// If the user isn't logged in, just return 4 (default styling)
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
return 4;
}
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->id;
$user_team = xprofile_get_field_data( 3, 1 );
```

In this code, the field ID is fixed to 3 and the user ID is fixed to 1 (my user ID). Originally I used $user_id for the user ID, but this didn't work.

The problem with this code is, $user_team just returns string(0) "" if I run the code with a var_dump. Then, if I go and check the field in my profile in the backend, it's not filled in. However, when I don't run this code, the correct value is selected. I also can't change the value while this code is active.

Does someone know how to fix this (probably very easy) issue? I've already used bp_get_profile_field_data(), but this gave the exact same result.

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: Hi there, welcome to WPSE. As a third-party plugin Buddypress is off-topic here - we don't have the required knowledge to really help you thoroughly with this. You might want to try asking at the Buddypress forums instead.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was made by the WordPress team. At least their site is linked to the WordPress.org site, so I assumed it was made by them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to the context of your code - which you didn't explain.

Try this in your-theme/functions.php

```
function hisgen_check() {
   echo 'field: ' . xprofile_get_field_data( 3, bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'comma' );
}
add_action( 'bp_ready', 'hisgen_check' );
```

Comment: Thank you! That code did it. The code I posted was the code I had in a function, and I then called that function directly. The only thing I don't want it to, is to echo it. I want to use this function for other parts of my theme, like getting a different stylesheet depending on the entered value.

I think it didn't work because I didn't use a hook. Thanks again! :)